# Bivariate and multivariate statistics in java

Tags: java, statistics

I am looking for a common package to do bivariate and multivariate statistics in java. Any ideas or recommandations?

thx

Comment: Have you looked at this : http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/stat.html